# Load CSS from a locally hosted file

Tags: html, css

For site styling purposes with a CMS that is running on a server, is it possible to have a browser pointing at a page but load its CSS from a locally hosted file?  I would like to run SASS for local CSS development, but get the HTML content from a centrally hosted CMS server.

Comment: for security reasons, pages loaded from non-local urls (e.g. http://) cannot load/access content from file:/// urls. You can have "external" css, it just has to be hosted on an actual webserver and accessed via http

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might find [Chrome developer tools' Workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces) feature useful:

> ## Mapping a Network Resource
>
> The real power of Workspaces lies in being able to map a local file to
> a URL (or “Network Resource”). Whenever Chrome loads the mapped URL,
> it displays the workspace folder contents in place of the network
> folder contents. It’s as if it’s being served on the web, but you can
> modify it with DevTools and save the changes persistently to the local
> file.

The article contains instructions about how to setup your workspace environment so I will not repeat them here.